# Why I get error saying function in argument for a class not defined - error FS0039: The value or constructor 'function' is not defined

Tags: class, oop, f#

I have a class called 'car', which can instantiate objects.

```
type car (fuelEco: float,fuel:int) =
    let mutable fuelEco = fuelEco
    let mutable tank = 0
    member this.addGas (liter: int) = tank <- liter
    member this.gasLeft () = tank
    member this.drive (km: int) =
        if float(km) > (float(tank) * fuelEco) then raise (InsuficientGas "You can't drive this far - you have insuficient amount of gas")
        else tank <- tank - int((float(km) / fuelEco))
```

I have another class called 'Assert' (with capital letter), which asserts a number of arguments given to the class Assert.

```
type Assert (str: string, a:'a, b: 'b,f:('a -> 'a -> bool)) =
    static member test = 
        if (f a (int(b))) then 
            printfn "%A : %A" "Pass" str
        else printfn "%A : %A" "Pass" str
```

I then have to test Assert by the follwing code:

```
let fe = 18.3
let mini = new car(fe,0)
Assert.test "GasLeft () - Full?" (mini.gasLeft ()) 10.0 (=)
Assert.test "GasLeft () - Empty?" (mini.gasLeft ()) 0 (=)
```

For the first test, I would expect to get "Fail" : "GasLeft () - Full?"
and for the second test, I would expect to get "Pass" : "GasLeft() - Empty?"
when given the arguments specified.

However, F# tells me that f is not defined in the arguments. My f when calling Assert.test is (=), which according to F# takes ('a -> 'a -> bool). Note that I cast b to and int, because it can be given as a float type, so to be sure, that I compare two integers, I cast it to an int first.

So I can't see why it says f is not defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your `Assert` class. The arguments were going into the class constructor instead of the static member. A static member does not have access to the state of the class and therefore you get an error.

I fixed this by moving the arguments to the `test` member and also changed them from being tupled arguments (comma separated) to curried arguments (space separated) so that they can be called in the curried style as you were doing.

```ml
type Assert =
    static member test (str: string) (a:'a) (b: 'b) (f:('a -> 'a -> bool)) = 
        if (f a (int(b))) then 
            printfn "%A : %A" "Pass" str
        else printfn "%A : %A" "Pass" str
```

There seems to be some dangerous mixing of floats and ints. I recommend changing all the number types here to be float, which should make the code more simple and correct.

Comment: Beautiful, it works now. Thanks! So it is only if it is static that it can't access the header/state of class (if header and state of class is the same)?

If it had not written static it would be able to access the state?

Comment: @morten Yes, but then you would call it like this: `Assert("GasLeft () - Full?", (mini.gasLeft ()), 10.0, (=)).test()`, which I don't think is what you desired. In fact I'm not sure why you are using a class here at all. In F# you use modules, functions and data as a starting point and classes only if necessary. You probably don't need any classes to solve your problem.